# Olympus ME52 Mic Not Working in Ubuntu

Tags: sound, windows, microphone, skype

My Olympus microphone is not working in Ubuntu on Skype or in the Sound Recorder application.

It works fine on Windows 7 without the need for me to ever do anything. My computer doesn't have a mic, so I just bought this little one that plugs straight into the Mic input.

Is there anything I need to do to get it working? It's annoying because I can't Skype in Ubuntu I have to boot into Windows 7, which I don't enjoy.

Comment: In your audio settings (last entry in the speaker menu top right), what device is selected in the input tab? And make sure it is not muted.

Comment: Wow haha. Thanks. It was just muted. I wonder why that is the default?

Comment: It's muted by default because some hardware can be damaged when both the mic(s) and speakers are unmuted.  Maintaining a whitelist of known-working combinations would be cumbersome, too.

Answer (score 3):

From the first and second comments to the question, I have a feeling that the question is answered by @david:

> In your audio settings (last entry in the speaker menu top right), what device is selected in the input tab? **And make sure it is not muted**.